# How to keep python programming running constantly

Tags: python, macos, praw

I made a program that grabs the top three new posts on the r/wallpaper subreddit. It downloads the pictures every 24 hours and adds them to my wallpapers folder. What I'm running into is how to have the program running in the background. The program resumes every time I turn the computer on, but it pauses whenever I close the computer. Is there a way to close the computer without pausing the program? I'm on a mac.

Comment: run it on **the internet**?

Comment: How? Do I use cgi?

Comment: It all depends where you would host it. If hosting on a linux platform, you could use a `cron` job to fire off your python script. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Run it on a computer that is never turned off. You do this by either setting up your own server or by renting one online.

Answer (score 0):

Programs can't run when the computer is powered off. However, you can run a computer headlessly (without mouse, keyboard, and monitor) to save resources. Just ensure your program runs over the command line interface.